# The Android App Bundle was not signed using react native

Tags: android, react-native

I get the above error when I try and upload my .aab file to the play console.

After following the react-native docs, and running:

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore xxx.keystore -alias xxx -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then, `./gradlew bundleRelease`.

It creates the following file:

```
./android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab
```

When I upload this I get the error.

How can I sign my app?

**Update:**

I actually missed a set out from the docs. Although, when I sign my app I get your

> Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: 7C:AC:....yadda....:B6:E9:8A.

I am using a .keystore file from a previous app I have uploaded with no problems.

Comment: Actually i think problem is in your keystore previously you upload apk on google play store with different keystore and your current keystore signature is not match with previous keystore

Comment: I have my original keystore, the SHA1 stated in the error, matches the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint displayed in the app releases page. Any ideas why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post I can't figure out if you've also performed the middle parts of the walkthrough.

[Setting up Gradle variables](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#setting-up-gradle-variables)

1. Place the my-upload-key.keystore file under the android/app
   directory in your project folder.
2. Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties or
   android/gradle.properties, and add the following (replace ***** with
   the correct keystore password, alias and key password)

[Adding signing config to your app's Gradle config](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config)

The last configuration step that needs to be done is to setup release builds to be signed using upload key. Edit the file android/app/build.gradle in your project folder, and add the signing config

Could you confirm you've done this or either perform these steps and try again

Comment: Updated question, I actually missed out a step in the docs. I have a previously uploaded an app last year. I am using that same .keystore

Comment: Well that seems strange, is it a new app you're trying to launch or are you trying to update an app which is already in the store?

Comment: It's a new app, but I've uploaded an app last year, using my original keystore, the SHA1 key is the same in the error as is displayed on the app release page, so it must be the same? Any ideas?

Comment: Well the only cases where I've seen this is when the wrong key was used to upload the app to the play store. So there are two things I can image you can try. First try to rebuild the entire project and generate the signed APK or Bundle once again and reupload. Else the only thing I can think of is that you're either trying to upload it to the wrong project (it happens) or you should contact play console support and request to reset the key